# Nginx redirect all mobile traffic to folder

Tags: nginx

When I go to mydomain.com the mobile redirection works but when I go to some other pages it fails and serves the original link.

```
location / {

   if ($http_user_agent ~* "(iPhone|iPod|android|blackberry)" ) {
        return 301 $scheme://$host/m$request_uri;
    }

   index index.php;

}

location /m/ {
    index index.php;

}
```

any help please ?

I tried this but then i end up with a redirection loop

```
location ~ /page\.php.* {
if ($http_user_agent ~* "(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows (ce|phone)|xda|xiino") {
        return 301 /m$request_uri;
    }



}

location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files  $uri =404;
    fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include        fastcgi_params;
}
```

Comment: Am I doing it wrong ??

Comment: Yeah, you're matching `/` but nothing else.  Also, if you can help it, I strongly recommend **not** doing this sort of mobile redirection logic.  You'll never end up with a proper list of devices.  Besides, who's to say what a mobile device is these days?  There are large phones as big as small tablets.

Comment: @Brad can you please help set up the proper config file for this redirection to work

Comment: Put your if block outside the location block.